# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'inception_preprocessing'

Tags: python, deep-learning

```python
import inception_preprocessing
```

I wrote the above line but I am getting the following error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'inception_preprocessing'
```

Where I am wrong?

Comment: Well you are wrong in expecting that importing any random module will work out of the box. I am not sure what module you expect to import, but by default there is no module with that name. You need to provide more information about what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You should do `pip install preprocessing` and then import like

```
from preprocessing import inception_preprocessing
```

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when you have not installed this module in your system. First go to the address where Python is installed in your system and under Scripts directory(Eg- C:\Users\Roshan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts), then Open Command Prompt to this path and type- pip install , to install this module into your system. Then use the import command in your program. You can also go to this link and search for the modules required with its pip command--> https://pypi.org/